# How to convert an address stored in char array to actual address?

Tags: c

I have following char array:

```
char hex[16] = "0x7fffa410c240"
```

How can i convert it into numerical address that can be assigned to another variable.
Important is that i have to keep the base of value remaining the same i.e. 16 (hexadecimal).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void *ptr;
sscanf(hex, "%p", &ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks R, but it give following error with the use of void:  "error: `void*' is not a pointer-to-object type"

Answer (score 6):

Try the function [`strtoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) which returns `unsigned long long`.

On Visual Studio `strtoull` is not available, but [`_strtoui64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85zk715d.aspx) can probably be used.

#### EDIT

As [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) mentions in the comments you should probably use `sscanf(hex, "%p", ..)` or `strtoumax` which has the same prototype as `strtoull` but returns an `uintmax_t`.

Comment: `unsigned long long` is not the same as `uint64_t` though it's at least as wide.

Comment: Sorry, I must have edited in between, so I changed that to unsigned long long.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko No problem. I see you also changed the link.

Comment: `long long` is not necessarily large enough to hold pointers. Either use `strtoumax` or `sscanf` with the right format for a void pointer (`%p`) or `uintmax_t` (`%ju`).

Comment: @R.. Good call, I hadn't noticed "convert an **address**".